# dataframe.transpose() didn't transpose

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe df5 which I want to transpose the columns into rows and vice-versa,

```
DayofWeek   Avg_Shopping_Trips  Avg_Profit
0   5.Saturday  1096.750000 185040.397500
1   6.Sunday    1489.666667 178546.993333
```

I tried the following code but it didn't work.  What am I doing wrong here?  Please help.

```
df5.transpose()
df5
```

Comment: You can simply do this: `df5 = df5.T`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to assign a new value to df5.

Try

```
df5=df5.transpose()
```